# How to write drivers to be copied and pasted between objects' modifiers?

Tags: scripting, drivers

- I have assigned a script-expression driver to a field in a modifier.
- The expression is a function of properties of the object to which the modifier is assigned, extracted as Single Property variables.

I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> link the modifier to a new object. I can copy the driver from the old object's modifier, and paste it into the new object's modifier.

But, of course, the driving properties still refer to the old object, and so I have to go in and manually point the variables in the driver to the new object.

How should I use 'self', or suchlike, either in an expression, or in a driver-namespace function, so I can copy the driver between modifiers on separate objects, always referring to the object the modifier is assigned to?

EDIT:

I've just worked out that `self` in an expression driving a modifier field, refers to the *modifier*, not the object the modifier is assigned to.

AND YET, if I create single-property variables to be used in the expression in the UI, the root is the *object*. For example, to reach the value of a field in the driven modifier *that* way, I use `modifiers["name"].modifier_property`.

This makes no sense to me at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The id_data property of any object returns an ID object**

Simple example adding a driver to the count of an array modifier  The modifier is on the default cube.

[image]

The driver script, prints out `self`,  `self.id_data` the path from `self.id_data` to `self` and returns 2.

```
import bpy

def test(self):
    print(self)
    print(self.id_data)
    print(self.path_from_id())
    return 2

bpy.app.driver_namespace["test"] = test
```

Here is the output to console

```
<bpy_struct, ArrayModifier("Array")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>
modifiers["Array"]
```

Hence other properties of the modifier can be accessed using `self.other_modifier_property` and properties of the object it is on via `self.id_data.some_object_property`

The driver UI deals in ID objects, as does the datapath used by fcurves etc.  You select the (ID) `bpy.types.Object` instance the modifier is on, and add the datapath from ID object to modifier. In this case `self = self.id_data.modifiers["Array"]`

Comment: Phew! Thank you. This begins to crack open a lot more than this particular problem, for me. I've been able to go back and read the API introduction and `bpy_struct` with a bit more understanding. I  often wish the documentation for this and other APIs would kick off with more of a view from 30 000 ft - How to _look_  at the data structures / database, in plain language, before considering how to use them.

Comment: It's the string representation of most blender objects `str(obj)` Consider  `<bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>` an instance of `bpy.types.Object` named "Cube".  Printing `repr(self.id_data)` would return `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]`